# Creating Multi Indexed Dataframe with Its Name - Pandas/Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Assuming I have this dataframe saved in my directory:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

col1 = pd.Series(np.linspace(1, 10, 20))
col2 = pd.Series(np.linspace(11, 20, 20))
data = np.array([col1, col2]).T
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ["col1", "col2"])
df.to_csv("test.csv", index = False)
```

What I would like to do is to read this file and the name of the file as a column on top of the other columns to get something like this:

[image: example]

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pathlib` to extract the file name using `.stem` and `pd.concat` to create a multi level column:

```
import pathlib

filename = pathlib.Path('path/to/test.csv')

df = pd.concat({filename.stem.capitalize(): pd.read_csv(filename)}, axis=1)
print(df)

# Output:
         Test           
         col1       col2
0    1.000000  11.000000
1    1.473684  11.473684
2    1.947368  11.947368
3    2.421053  12.421053
4    2.894737  12.894737
5    3.368421  13.368421
6    3.842105  13.842105
7    4.315789  14.315789
8    4.789474  14.789474
9    5.263158  15.263158
10   5.736842  15.736842
11   6.210526  16.210526
12   6.684211  16.684211
13   7.157895  17.157895
14   7.631579  17.631579
15   8.105263  18.105263
16   8.578947  18.578947
17   9.052632  19.052632
18   9.526316  19.526316
19  10.000000  20.000000
```

Comment: I updated my answer in a more convenient way.

Comment: hmmm, I think same problem, `concat` is used for join multiple DataDrame in list, dict.... Not for create MultiIndex ;) So working, but hack.

Comment: Maybe, the OP wants to set the filename at the top level column because he has many dataframes from different files to concatenate :)

Comment: hmmm, I read again question and no info about it.

Comment: @Corralien Actually i do have so many dataframes from different files and i want to concat them. How did you know? :))

Comment: @eh329 - yes, best add to question.

Comment: @jezrael I really did not want to complicate the queestion. I think i needed to add extra examples for that too.

Comment: @eh329 - ya, agree. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html):

```
file = 'test.csv'

df = pd.read_csv(file)
name = file.split('.')[0].capitalize()

df.columns= pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[name],df.columns])
print (df.head())
       Test           
       col1       col2
0  1.000000  11.000000
1  1.473684  11.473684
2  1.947368  11.947368
3  2.421053  12.421053
4  2.894737  12.894737
```